# What is the easiest way to find Esperantized names of cities?

Tags: translation, pasporta-servo

For a trip I am planning I have been looking in the pasporta servo for people in India.

I've tryed searching for cities by the name from Google maps, but not a lot of people were found. Then I figured out that the city names would most likely be not in English, but in Esperanto form.

And I am having a tough luck finding a good resource that would help me get Esperantized names of cities.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorio:Urboj_de_Barato Or are you looking for smaller and/or less-known cities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenStreetmap(OSM) is a free/open database of geographical info in the world. Many city nodes contain their Esperanto translation. (anybody can contribute in OSM to add more translations)

You can filter by country:
http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/khW

or get all the current world cities with Esperanto name:
http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ki0

Comment: Great resource! And there is room for contributions, since many big city nodes do not not contain Eo translation.

Answer (score 9):

A good way is to find the city on English Wikipedia then click the *Esperanto* on the list of languages.  Of course, that supposes that the city is large enough to have an Esperanto Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3):

I have to add that on pasportaservo at this point the search option is not in its best state. In theory, you can type in Esperanto, or "local" names with latin spelling, but you might not get good search results. We are working on bettering the search options only after the booklet is ready as it is priority. In the future you can search both better. Now you can search both, not so well. ;-)

So the issue is with the search engine, not your ability to type in the correct names. ;-) Sorry about that, we ask for a bit more patience.

/I do a lot of admin for Pasporta Servo./

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to find out what the esperanto name for a city, if it doesn't appear on the numerous lists of city names on the internet, is to search up if that city has an **esperanto community**. If they do, they would say what the city name is in the title or on their website (This is how I found out how to say Ottawa in esperanto, Otavo).

It could also be useful to  search up the city on **Pasporta Servo**, or simply **guessing** what you think the city name is and **searching it up on Google** to see if others also refer to it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Another automatic way will be to ask Wikidata to give you all the Esperanto cities fetched.

http://tinyurl.com/zsmtlb6

Comment: The OP was interested in cities in India, perhaps you could show how to restrict results to a particular country, as it's not obvious.